# Return record from a database table using Apache CXF

Tags: web-services, cxf

I am using Apache CXF (apache-cxf-2.5.0) to create Web Services using a bottom-up approach (Java first approach). I want to return some data/records (for example, username, email) from a database table. I can write a Java class which returns a simple response. But I am not able to find way to return a response such as data/records extracted from a database table. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention how you are accessing the database, but the basic idea is that you ensure that the classes that you return have JAXB annotations (notably [`@XmlRootElement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlRootElement.html) or [`@XmlType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlType.html)) on them, which allows CXF to convert the instances of those classes into XML document fragments. The classes which you annotate this way probably should not have lots of functionality in them; they should exist just to hold data. (I find anything else too confusing given the complex lifecycle they'll have.) Once the annotations are in place, just return the relevant objects and all the conversions will happen automatically.

I'm talking a simple class like this:

```java
@XmlRootElement    //  <---- THIS LINE HERE!
public class UserInfo {
    public String username;
    public String email;
}
```

You can use this in conjunction with other annotations (e.g., for your ORM) as necessary. Of course, if you're talking straight JDBC to the DB to get the information out, you won't need to worry about that.

---

The one tricky bit is that the objects being returned will have a lifespan that goes beyond that of the database transaction you're using; you may need to detach (i.e., do some copying, though the ORM layer might provide assistance) the objects extracted from the DB for that to work. This won't be much of a concern in this case as the DB you're describing is very simple (one table, no inter-row relations) but could be an issue if you make things more complex.

Comment: Thank you Donal for your answer. I am creating CXF (apache-cxf-2.5.0) SOAP based Web Services. It creates WSDL from Java class (Java first approach). I have to use SOAP and can't use REST. 

I am retrieving data from database using ResultSet. Data is about 5 columns and over 100 rows. Now I want to send this data to Android client. I am thinking of converting ResultSet into ArrayList and sending ArrayList / List object as a response from SOAP Web Service. My problem is - is it possible to send List object as a reponse from SOAP Web Service. If yes, please provide me link to such an examples.

Comment: @waprau: If it's a list of objects that are all tagged with appropriate JAXB annotations, then yes. The main problem will be ensuring that all the concrete types that it could contain are described in the WSDL so that the client knows to tool for them too; I've yet to find a good answer there except for having a separate method that returns a single object of each of the classes (or a superclass, with some `@XmlSeeAlso` magic).

Comment: Is it possible to use JAXB annotations for SOAP Web Service?

Comment: @waprau: I don't think you can (usefully) put them on the JAXWS-enabled methods, but you *can* put them on the classes of the objects returned. I don't remember if they work when place on `Foo` where the return type is `List<Foo>` (well, they work _per se_ but might not be picked up).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Does it mean, it doesn't work with SOAP Web Service? If it doesn't work with SOAP Web Service, whats the solution to return such ResultSet from SOAP Web Service? Thanks again.

Comment: It will work as long as you can get your schema(s) published and linked together correctly. Or you can hack it for specific clients by forcing the JAXB context to have the extra classes you need (details of which are googlable; I found them while researching my answer) but that's inelegant and not very portable to other clients.

Comment: Then whats the elegant & portable way to return such a ResultSet from SOAP Web Service? Can you provide links to such resources? Thanks.